# AsyncIterator exits "for await-of" loop abruptly

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, iterator, generator

I'm trying to build a `buffer` backed `AsyncIterator` to produce the values from the buffer when buffer is not empty & `await` on a `Promise` if buffer is empty.

```js
class PushGenerator {
  constructor() {
    this.buffer = []
    this.pending = null
  }
  
  // push values to iterator. `null` will stop the iterator
  push(value) {
    if (this.pending) {
      this.pending(value)
      this.pending = null
      return
    }
    this.buffer.push(value)
  }
  
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let event = null
    
    while(true) {
        if (this.buffer.length > 0) event = this.buffer.shift()
      else event = await new Promise(r => this.pending = r)
      
      if (event !== null) yield event
      else break
    } 
  }
}

async function main() {
  const gen = new PushGenerator()
  setTimeout(() => gen.push(10), 10)

  for await (const item of gen) {
     console.log("---", item)
  }
  
  setTimeout(() => gen.push(null), 3000)
  console.log('Im not called!')
}

main().then(v => console.log('never called', v))
  .catch(e => console.log('never called', e))
```

For most parts it works fine, except that if I `push` the values **after** the `await for-of` loop, its completely ignored. Infact the `async main` itself terminates without resolving/rejecting the promise!. My expectation is that `for await-of` loop to wait for values until loop is broken or `null` is sent to the `PushGenerator`

Behaviour is same both in nodejs & also in chrome. Googling didnt help much & not able to find any similar question in SO as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like you have a promise that never resolves.

Comment: @Yousaf But I would expect the `for await-of` to wait in that case. Something like slow-producer -> fast-consumer

Comment: i think `for of` loop is waiting for the promise that never resolves. That is why statements after `for of` loop are not executed.

Comment: But if I run it in `nodejs`, the program exits abruptly. In the debugger, I see it reaching upto `new Promise(r => this.pending = r)` & then it just stops! Could this be some quirk in nodejs? If so, how to get around this?

Comment: I just tested the code in safari, chrome and nodejs and i am getting same results in each environment. After logging 10, `for-of` loop is _waiting_ for the promise to _resolve_ which never happens in your case.

Comment: It does work as expected if I do `Promise.race` & `sleep`. Otherwise it still exits for me in nodejs. https://jsfiddle.net/sudhh/gLbrs8a9/1/

Comment: @Yousaf does the snippet require any changes to make it work or does it work as it is?

Comment: snippet only logs 10.

Comment: Yes, it only logs 10 & exits. Only with `Promise.race` & `sleep`, I'm able to make it work

Comment: I don't think it exits; for me, it keeps waiting for the promise to resolve. I am not sure what's happening at your end.

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be my node version. But I've tested it in `v15.6.0`, `v14.16.0` & `v12.21.0`. It still exits after printing `--- 10`. For now I'm happy with the `Promise.race` version. BTW, thanks for your hint on `promise that never resolves`

Comment: okay. It does work as expected in node REPL & in browser. Just that when run as a program, it exits (`node itr.js`)!

Comment: As long as reference to `gen` is kept alive outside `main`, the loop awaits. Then nodejs terminates the loop 